# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'” error

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
 public bool GetHolidays(DataSet ds,List<string> dates,DataTable dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dates.Count; i++)
        {
            bool weekOff = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x=>(x.Field<string>("WeekOffDays")==dates[i]).ToString()).Any(); // error in this line

            if(weekOf)
               return true;

            return false;
        }
     }
```

I get the error that says:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

To overcome this I tried:

```
   DateTime dateTime;
   bool weekOff = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x=>DateTime.TryParse((x.Field<string> 
     ("WeekOffDays")==dates[i]).ToString(),out dateTime)).Any();
```

but still the error persists.

I tried with DateTime but when I write it, it gives me another error saying

> Operator == cannot be used for DateTime and string

**Please note:** The column **WeekOffDays** is of type **datetime**

How this can be solved?

Comment: try to change it to ``x.Field<DateTime>`` in the second query

Comment: I tried, but it gave me this error: Operator == cannot be used for DateTime and string

Comment: yes, try @HienNguyen answer

Comment: ``WeekOffDays`` type is varchar or dateTime2?

Comment: @Sajid, it is of datetime

Comment: so, try``ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(x => (x.Field<DateTime>("WeekOffDays")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == dates[i])`` bu using the right format of the ``ToString()``

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: @Sajid, the ToString() is saying " Unable to Convert to string to IFormatProvider "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211423/discussion-between-sajid-and-noobprogrammer).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need toString in where, it should be

```
  bool weekOff = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => 
                    x.Field<string>("WeekOffDays") == dates[i]).Any();
```

This is method i tried reproduce in local machine.

```
public bool GetHolidays(DataSet ds, List<string> dates, DataTable dt)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dates.Count; i++)
            {
                bool weekOff = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("WeekOffDays") == dates[i]).Any(); // error in this line

                if (weekOff)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: is it the only reason why I am getting this error? I tried to remove ToString() previously, but was getting that same error.

Comment: still getting the same error:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.